# How do I generate a word cloud for a large dataset in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, large-data, word-cloud

I'm trying to generate a word cloud for a year's worth of complaint narrative data from the CFPB's [public complaint database](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/data-research/consumer-complaints/).

There are roughly 100,000 words per year.

I've been able to generate clouds using samples of about 1,000 words per year. I use a tibble with words and frequencies for each year.

I've tried `wordcloud` and `ggwordcloud` so far and both packages seem to run forever or freeze when I try using them on a full year's worth of data. My machine has 16GB of RAM. Is it capable of handling this much data?

Does anyone know if there's a package I can use to generate word clouds for datasets this large?

I've seen previous answers that recommend taking samples or otherwise reducing the size of data that I'm working with. I still want to work with the full dataset if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Reading in chunks to accumulate a word list is one option. Here's some code that uses the function `read_lines_chunked` from the `readr` package. Each chunk is processed using the `tidytext` package and the output from a previous chunk is used to create an accumulating word list. From there, the `wordcloud` package is used.

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(wordcloud)
library(readr)
    
process_chunk <- function(x, pos, acc) {
    df <- tibble(text=x)
    words <- 
        unnest_tokens(df, 'word', 'text') %>%
        anti_join(stop_words, by = 'word') %>%
        bind_rows(acc) %>%
        count(word, sort = T)
    rm(df)
    words
}
    
words <- read_lines_chunked('complaints.csv', AccumulateCallback$new(process_chunk), chunk_size = 100000)
    
words %>%
    head(50) %>%
    with(wordcloud(word, n))
```

[image]

The creation of the word list took about 30 minutes on my 16Gb laptop.

Obviously, you'll have to tune your code to add or remove words of interest. I eliminated stop words and you might want to decide what to do with `xxxx` which I think is a substitute for cross people saying rude words.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. For me the issue isn't the creation of the word list, I have that working just fine. It's the final rendering of the word cloud - for instance, I'm feeding all 100,000 words into ```wordcloud``` and trying to get a cloud that big. I notice you only took 50 rows from ```words``` to use in your word cloud.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. 100,000 words in a cloud would be very hard to read and in my experience I don't recollect seeing more than a few hundred in a single cloud so I'm not surprised the `wordcloud` function does not think about rendering such a large number. I would imagine that the rendered image would be large. My back of an envelope estimates each word needs 100 pixels by 100 pixels to render visibly resulting in 1 billion pixels. If a pixel needs 1 byte then that's 1Gb as an image size.

Comment: That sounds about right to me as well. I'll leave this open in case anyone else knows of a package that might be able to handle something this big. In the meantime I'll work with less words. Thanks!